# Finding average score from all user's maximum score in django orm

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to calculate the average score from all finished exam. Users can send an exam as much as they want. So, the data of the finished exam can be like...

(User, Finished exam's score)

(1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 8)

I want average score of all highest score of each user.

A expected average score of above data should be 7. "(10+3+8) / 3"

#### My django model

```py
class Exam(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField("Title")
    description = models.TextField("Description")

class Question(models.Model):
    exam_id = models.ForeignKey("Exam", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Question")
    score = models.FloatField(default=1)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question_id = models.ForeignKey("Question", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Answer")

class FinishedExam(models.Model):
    exam = models.ForeignKey("Exam", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_score = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first annotate for every use the maximum score, and then aggregate over that set:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Max

User.objects.annotate(
    max_score=Max('finishedexam__score')
).aggregate(
    avg_score=Avg('max_score')
)['avg_score']
```

This will yield a query that looks like:

```
SELECT AVG(max_score)
FROM (
    SELECT auth_user.id AS Col1, MAX(core_finishedexam.score) AS max_score
    FROM auth_user
    LEFT OUTER JOIN core_finishedexam ON auth_user.id = core_finishedexam.user_id
    GROUP BY auth_user.id ORDER BY NULL
) subquery
```

The subquery will thus generate the maximum score per user, and then we calculate the average.

If you want to filter for a specific exam, you can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import Avg, Max

User.objects.filter(
    finishedexam__exam=my_exam
).annotate(
    max_score=Max('finishedexam__score')
).aggregate(
    avg_score=Avg('max_score')
)['avg_score']
```

This will then only take the average for the users that made that exam (at least once). So users that never made *`my_exam`* will then be ignored.